# Under which circumstances would CAN communication still work if there is no bus termination?

Tags: can, bus, termination

The bus termination is needed to prevent reflections. Does this mean that it may be possible to get a working communication with a low data rate, since then reflections might not interfere with the new message?

Comment: Data rate matters much less than rise/fall time of the driver. But the whole stuff works very well with very short cable.

Comment: So the answer to this question would be "no it does not matter if there is a low or high data rate as long as the cable is short" ?

Comment: The proper operation of dominant vs recessive bits on the bus requires some resistance between the canh and canl lines to pull the line down to the recessive state if no one is transmitting a dominant bit.  You might be able to get away with no terminations in some circumstances but not recommended

Comment: Yes. Partial answer. Complete one would be supported by calculated cable length, recommendation to use termination anyway and so on.

Comment: Not a low data rate but a low bit rate. That means you would have to pause between every bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even with a very short bus length, CAN bus will not work without at least one resistor between CAN Low and CAN High. The resistor is needed to pull the bus into the recessive state.

Answer (score 0):

Under unreliable ones.

Even though it should work with short cables and/or slow data rates, there would bé nous guarantee from their maker regarding the transceiver's behavior when its output (the CAN bus wires) do not have the proper impedance. It will thus have no guarantee whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

CAN receivers has input resistors, as part of implementing voltage dividers to accept CAN bus differential levels that are far above or far below the expected levels. These "far above, far below" occur when SHORTS occur.

Depending on leakage currents (the temperature) and the # of receivers (# of input resistors and bus length (capacitance), you may even succeed with full data rates.

10Kohm and 100pF is 1 uS tau. Far better to depend on the usual (60 ohm?) terminations.